# Need a query to get top N rows from MySQL database based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL as follows.

```
studentId  studentName status
```

Here studentId is the ID of the student ,name is his/her name and status is pass/fail. I need a MySQL query to return the top N rows based on the condition that the student has passed. For instance ,if the table contains

```
0001  Sam   Pass
1190  Mary  Fail
2320  John   Pass
2536  Micheal  Pass
3010  Rose    Pass
```

and lest say n = 3
the query should return.

```
0001  Sam   Pass
2320  John   Pass
2536  Micheal  Pass
```

Is there a way to do it in MySQL.

Comment: you can use limit in your query.

Comment: couldn't you just say studentId<253, and such?

Comment: what is 253? please share more details.

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE `status` = "Pass"
LIMIT 3;
```

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)

In your case, since you just want the top rows, you don't need two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit` ::

**n** is the number of rows you want

```
Select
* 
from 
student
limit n
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM tablue wheq STATUS = 'Pass' LIMIT 0, 3`

tablue is the table name